# Restrict access to apache document root but not for subdomains

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, virtualhost

I'm running Apache on CentOS 7. I have configured multiple virtual hosts. Their root directories are in `/var/www/html/{example.com, sub1.example.com, etc.}`. I have also configured a `000-default.conf` vhost to redirect all incoming traffic (which is not covered by one of the virtual hosts) to the main document root (`/var/www/html`) and show a blank page.

But know I face a critical security issue: If a visitor is redirected into the document root with the blank index.html file, he can append the URL with "/example.com" and visit this directory. This might not seem dangerous, but imagine if for example a Laravel application is installed there, which has it's one public folder (`/var/www/html/example.com/public`). Then a visitor would be able to browse the laravel directory with all it's configuration files!

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent directory listings using the following apache directives:

```
Options -Indexes
```

You can set this globally in httpd.conf, for a particular directory using the `<Directory </Directory>` block as below or using `.htaccess` file inside the directory.

```
<Directory /var/www/html/example.com/public>
  Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

For further reference: [Directory Listing Configuration](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings)

Comment: Okay, thanks. But one last thing: A visitor could still guess filenames and view these files. Is there a way to prevent a vistor who knows the servers ip (which points to the main document root) to even access a sub directory?

Comment: @LuMa, it's not clear what you mean by "view the files". A visitor normally see the pages as served by the web server and that's why you have a web server running. And for your other question, it depends how have you configured your server. If you have name based virtual hosting configured, then a visitor should not be able to access the subfolders using ip address. You better take some time to understand how apache works and how to secure it. Anyway, If this answer has helped you, then you may accept it as an answer.